# Detecting mouse device file programmatically

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-device-driver

I am developing a software which needs to read from the mouse and keyboard device file. I can find them in `/sys/proc/bus/input/devices` . But I want my program to detect them automatically and use in its purpose. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Learn about [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) and use `/dev/input`

Comment: I bet you have the Xserver on, since you use a mouse. In that case, why don't you use the Xlib ?

Comment: Please tell little about your program.

Comment: For mouse you can use **/dev/input/mice** to read the data